# Базы данных lazarus

Tags: база-данных, lazarus

Есть 2 формы. На первой `DBGrid, Datasource, dbf`. На второй форме `TImage`. Как сделать, чтобы при переходе с записи на запись в таблице на второй форме автоматически менялись картинки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что лучше всего сделать так: создать модуль данных и кинуть все невизуальные компоненты для работы с БД туда, подключить его к обеим формам, а на второй форме вместо TImage поставить TDBImage и связать его с нужной таблицей и полем.

Comment: нужно именно так, как написано в описании

Comment: Тогда другой вариант: в обработчике события DataSource OnDataChange загружать данные из нужного поля в Image. Но это точно сложнее первого варианта, и тут придётся писать код.